# Select from list(of list(of object)) then split

Tags: .net, vb.net, algorithm, linq

I have groupped collection of Chars in VB.NET

something like

```
HashTable( 
          "A", List(OF Char) [ A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A],
          "B", List(OF Char) [ B,B,B,B,B],
          "C", List(OF Char) [ C,C,C]
         )
```

I want split that collection with **Linq** into **2+1** "pages"(new collection with 3 nested collection), each contains an equal number each char

for example from hashtable above th result should be

```
List( 
     list(of char) [ A,A,A,A,B,B,C ]
     list(of char) [ A,A,A,A,B,B,C ]
     list(of char) [ B,C ]  // LAST PAGE CONTAINS 
    )
```

Sorry for my english... thanks.

Comment: So, the 3rd list only ever contains 1 or 0 of each character (since if it contained 2, those would be split and placed onto the first 2 lists, same for even more)?

Comment: Cannot get your logic - why there is no A in last page? What if there will be seven A chars? How second page will look like?

Comment: So page 1 and page 2 will have, for each value v, count(v)/2 instances of v, and page 3 will have count(v) % 2 instances of v. Is that correct? All values are split evenly into the first two pages, and the last page gets the leftovers.

Comment: Yes corsiKa You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim input As New Dictionary(of Char, Char())
input.Add("A"c, {"A"c, "A"c, "A"c, "A"c, "A"c, "A"c, "A"c, "A"c})
input.Add("B"c, {"B"c, "B"c, "B"c, "B"c, "B"c})
input.Add("C"c, {"C"c, "C"c, "C"c})

Dim output As New List(of List(Of Char))
output.Add(input.SelectMany(Function(c) Enumerable.Repeat(c.Key, c.Value.Count \ 2)).ToList())
output.Add(output(0).ToList())
output.Add(input.SelectMany(Function(c) Enumerable.Repeat(c.Key, c.Value.Count Mod 2)).ToList())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is at least near to your desired result (the resulting list contains 3 lists with (6/5/5) chars):

```
Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Char)) From {
   {"A", New List(Of Char) From {"A"c, "A"c, "A"c, "A"c, "A"c, "A"c, "A"c, "A"c}},
   {"B", New List(Of Char) From {"B"c, "B"c, "B"c, "B"c, "B"c}},
   {"C", New List(Of Char) From {"C"c, "C"c, "C"c}}
```

}

```
Dim pageCount = 3
Dim allChars = dict.Values.SelectMany(Function(chr) chr)
Dim result As List(Of List(Of Char)) = allChars.
    Select(Function(chr, i) New With {.Char = chr, .Index = i}).
    GroupBy(Function(x) x.Index Mod pageCount).
    Select(Function(g) g.Select(Function(x) x.Char).ToList()).
    ToList()
```

This splits all chars in the `Values` property of your dictionary into a desired page count(3 in your example) by using `Enumerable.GroupBy` with the [`Mod` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank You for Your answer, but in Your example chars splitted into
` [ A,A,A,B,B,C ] , [A,A,A,B,C] , [A,A,B,B,C] ` ...

It is not what I want.

'@corsiKa' is right. 
"
Page 1 and page 2 will have, for each value v, count(v)/2 instances of v, and page 3 will have count(v) % 2 instances of v. All values are split evenly into the first two pages, and the last page gets the leftovers.
"

Comment: But there are 16 chars, so 2*8 and the 3rd page should be empty.

Comment: Please see my example of result in first post...
First pages should contain floor(A.count/pagecount) "A", floor(B.count/pagecount) "B" , floor(C.count/pagecount) "C"

last page contains leftovers . (A.count MOD pagecount) "A", (B.count MOD pagecount) "B",(C.count MOD pagecount) "C"

Answer (score 0):

Heh - amazing what mangling you can do with LINQ...here's a slightly different take than Tim's

(sorry, my VB is really rusty, but this should be more or less translatable)

```
var table = new Dictionary<char,List<char>>()
{
    {'A', new List<char>() {'A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A'}},
    {'B', new List<char>() {'B','B','B','B','B'}},
    {'C', new List<char>() {'C','C','C'}},      
};

var result = table
    .Select(kvp => new [] {
            new string(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.Count / 2), 
            new string(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.Count / 2), 
            new string(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.Count % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1) })
    .Aggregate((acc, entry) => new [] {
            acc[0] + entry[0], 
            acc[1] + entry[1], 
            acc[2] + entry[2]})
    .Select(s => s.ToCharArray().ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Ah, well that changes the stated problem, hence the solution...this only works due to the bolded "2+1" collections listed in the original problem.